# Mass transport equation Cartesian to polar coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, polar-coordinates

Can someone please advise on how to transform the following equation to polar coordinates?
$$\frac{\partial \rho(x,t)}{\partial t}=v\frac{\partial \left(\rho(x,t) L(x)\right)}{\partial x}+D\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(L(x)\frac{\partial \rho(x,t)}{\partial x}\right)$$

Comment: This looks like one dimensional equation (no $y$ and $z$), so no need to transform to polar coordinates

Comment: What polar coordinates? There is only a one-dimensional coordinate $x$ here

Comment: Maybe you mean $\partial_t \rho + \mathrm{div}(\rho V + D \nabla\rho)=0$? As in the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fokker%E2%80%93Planck_equation

Comment: You can write in several forms, see also here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convection%E2%80%93diffusion_equation

Comment: You just have to use the formula for the divergence in polar coordinates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [convection-diffusion equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convection%E2%80%93diffusion_equation)
$$
\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} = \nabla\cdot(\underbrace{D\, {\boldsymbol \nabla}\rho - \rho{\boldsymbol v}}_{-\boldsymbol f}) ,
$$
where $\rho$ is a species concentration (in mass transfer), $D$ is the diffusivity, ${\boldsymbol v} = v_r {\boldsymbol e}_r + v_\theta {\boldsymbol e}_\theta$ is the velocity field, and ${\boldsymbol f} = f_r {\boldsymbol e}_r + f_\theta {\boldsymbol e}_\theta$ is the flux. The differential operators write
$$
{\boldsymbol \nabla}\rho = \partial_r\rho\, {\boldsymbol e}_r + \frac{\partial_\theta\rho}{r}\, {\boldsymbol e}_\theta,
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\nabla\cdot {\boldsymbol f} = \frac{\partial_r (r f_r)}{r} + \frac{\partial_\theta f_\theta}{r}
$$
with the flux components $f_r = \rho v_r - D\partial_r\rho$ and $f_\theta = \rho v_\theta - D \partial_\theta\rho / r$.
If $D$ and $v$ do not depend on space (as seems to be the case here), we have
$$
\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} = \frac{D \partial_r (r \partial_r\rho) - v_r \partial_r(r\rho)}{r} + \frac{D/r\, \partial_{\theta\theta} \rho - v_\theta \partial_\theta\rho }{r} .
$$